# C# Win. Form - Where can i find designer of Crystal Report 2008?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am currently using **Visual Studio 2008** and **Crystal Report 2008**

### Question

Where can i **find designer of crystal report** (where every object has its own set of lines written which specifies the location,font etc of the object) like we have of windows form.

Any piece of information you can provide is appreciated

### Edit

**UI of the Form**

[image]

**Designer Of The Form**

[image]
. This is the designer of windows form and i am looking for the same designer code for crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Designer for crystal report is comes with Crystal Report 2008 itself :)

Comment: can you show me with help of image because whenever you expand the crystal report in the designer there is no location of every object mentioned in it.

Comment: please see the edit portion of the question to get a better look at my question

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As shown in image Textobject has different properties which you can modify as you can do in Windows form.
Hope above image solve your issue, otherwise plz explain in detail your query with the help of image.

Comment: please see the edit portion of the question to get a better look at my question

Answer (score 0):

To do above thing you need to use parameter in crystal reports and use reportobject property of reportdocument.ReportDefination to set desired properties as like windows forms designer code.

```
 ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();

    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();

for (int i = 0; i < reportDocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            TextObject MyText = (TextObject)reportDocument.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[i];

            MyText.ApplyFont(new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11f, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold));


        }
```

For more reference follow below links

http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/02/21/2554.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1386262.aspx?Dynamic+Parameters+in+C+asp+net

[Change column font style runtime in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765477/change-column-font-style-runtime-in-crystal-report)

[set fontstyle of a column of a crystal report programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779221/set-fontstyle-of-a-column-of-a-crystal-report-programatically)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?197900-how-to-dynamically-change-the-font-in-Crystal-Report

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: no i don't want to set its property i want to view its designer code like in higher version of crystal report

Comment: Currently I am using Crystal report 13 for VS2010 and not found such designer code behind for this version which is higher version than yours. Plz let me know where you find designer code in higher version of crystal report??